# Different android phones of the same model give different camera parameters

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I'm working with a specific phone model (Moto G) trying to collect uniform images with many devices.  Unfortunately, some of the phones are returning different parameter options (e.g.: one phone doesn't have any scene mode except "auto", while the rest of the Moto Gs have a wide range of scene modes).  Does anyone know why different devices of the same type would have different parameters available to them through the flattened parameters?

Also, if I try setting the scene mode to some value (e.g.: "sunset"), the phone doesn't crash--but does this mean that it's actually setting the scene mode correctly?  (In the past I've tried setting ISO values to nonexistent options and the phone crashed.  If the scene mode isn't recognized/set, why would it crash for bad ISOs but not bad scenes?